# Identifying the cotangent bundle of the flag variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is a Lie group (or I guess a linear algebraic group), $P \subset G$ a Lie subgroup with Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ respectively. In Chriss and Ginzburg's book "Representation theory and complex geometry" they have the following result (Lemma 1.4.9):

> There is a natural $G$-equivariant isomorphism
>   $$ T^*(G/P) \cong G \times_P \mathfrak{p}^\perp $$
>   where $\mathfrak{p}^\perp$ is the annihilator of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathfrak{g}^*$ and $P$ acts on $\mathfrak{p}^\perp$ by the coadjoint action.

They give a proof however I don't understand it at all. I will will reproduce it for convenience below (with some annotations that are my own!). I was hoping someone could help me fill in the details. I am actually interested in the algebraic version of the result but help understanding the proof in either the differential category or the algebraic one would be very useful!

*Proof*. Let $e = 1 \cdot P/P \in G/P$ be the base point. We have $T_e(G/P) = \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p}$ and $T_e^*(G/P) = (\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p})^* = \mathfrak{p}^\perp \subset \mathfrak{g}^*$. (*NOTE: ok up to here I understand, but the rest I have no idea*). It follows that, for any $g \in G$
$$T_{g \cdot e}^*(G/P) = g\mathfrak{p}^\perp g^{-1}. $$
**Question 1: So I understand that somehow I am meant to be able to transfer the tangent space at $e$ to the point $g \cdot e$ using the $G$ action but I'm unsure how to write this down.**

This shows that the vector bundles $T^*(G/P)$ and $ G \times_P \mathfrak{p}^\perp $ have the same fibers at each point of $G/P$, hence are equal as sets (*NOTE: ok I am happy with this if I can understand the above*). To prove that they are isomorphic as manifolds, one can refine the argument as follows.

Consider the trivial bundle $\mathfrak{g}_{G/P} = G/P \times \mathfrak{g}$ on $G/P$ with fiber $\mathfrak{g}$. The infinitesimal $\mathfrak{g}$-action on $G/P$ gives rise to a vector bundle morphism $\mathfrak{g}_{G/P} \longrightarrow T(G/P)$.

**Question 2: I understand that each element of the Lie algebra $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ gives rise to a vector field $\xi_X$, is the image of $(gP,X)$ under this map simply $\xi_X(gP)$?**

It is clear that the kernel of this morphism is the sub bundle $E \subset \mathfrak{g}_{G/P}$ whose fiber at a point $x \in G/P$ is the isotropy Lie algebra $\mathfrak{p}_x \subset \mathfrak{g}$ at $x$. This gives an isomorphism $T(G/P) \cong \mathfrak{g}_{G/P}/E$.

**Question 3: I don't know what is meant by the isotropy Lie algebra at the point but if I am correct in question 2 I would guess this is simply the tautological thing  - i.e. the elements of the lie algebra that act infinitesimally by zero?**

Further, the description of the fibers of $E$ gives an isomorphism $E \cong G \times_P (\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p})$.

**Question 4: I don't understand this at all**

Hence, $T(G/P) \cong G \times_P (\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p})$,

**Question 5: Didn't we just say that $T(G/P)$ was a quotient by this bundle?**

and the result follows by taking duals on each side. (*NOTE: That I am happy with*).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about the algebraic story so everything is a manifold for me.
The $G$-equivariant isomorphism $T^\ast (G/P) \cong G \times_P \mathfrak{p}^\perp$ is dual to the 
 $G$-equivariant isomorphism $T (G/P) \cong G \times_P (\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p})$.

Denote $\pi : G \longrightarrow G/P$  the smooth natural projection defined by $\pi(g) = gP$.
 To prove the latter, consider the morphism $f : G \times (\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p}) \longrightarrow T (G/P)$ defined by
 $$ (g, X + \mathfrak{p}) \mapsto d \pi_g \circ d(L_g)_e (X)$$
 where $L_g : G \longrightarrow G$ is the left multiplication. The map is well-defined since $d(L_g)_e (X) \in \ker d \pi_g$ if $X \in \mathfrak{p}$.
 For $h \in P$, $f(g h^{-1} , Ad_h (X) + \mathfrak{p}) = f(g, X) $ since $Ad_h = L_h \circ R_{h^{-1}}$ and $d \pi_{gh^{-1} } \circ d R_{h^{-1}} = d \pi_g$.
This shows that the map $f: G \times \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p} \longrightarrow T(G/P) $ 
descends to a map $\bar{f} : G \times_P \mathfrak{g} /\mathfrak{p}  \longrightarrow T(G/P)$. 
$\bar{f}$ is a smooth bijection and it induces a linear isomorphism on the fibers which is already true for $f$.

A standard lemma states that if $\phi : E \longrightarrow F$ is a morphism between vector bundles and it induces linear isomorphisms on fiber, 
then $\phi $ must be a diffeomorphism. (This follows from the fact that matrices being invertible is an open condition). 
So $\bar{f}$ is an isomorphism between vector bundles and taking the dual gives the desired result.

Comment: Can you clarify what $d\pi_g$ is? If it is the differential of $\pi$ at $g$, then $d\pi_g$ is a map $T_gG \to T_g(G/P)$, whereas $d(L_g)_e(X)$ is an element of $T_eG$.

Comment: $d(L_g)_e: T_e G \rightarrow T_g G$ is a map with target $T_g G$ so $d(L_g)_e(X)$ is an element of $T_g G$.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Could you clarify too the line starting with "For $h \in P$..." - I don't understand how $d\pi_{gh^{-1}} \circ dR_{h^{-1}} = d\pi_g$, nor how that gives the equality at the beginning. If on the other hand there's some resource you can point me to to better understand this reasoning that would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I understand the beginning equality now, but only if we assume $dL_g\vert_e (x) = gx$ and similarly for $dR_{h^{-1}}$. But as far as I understand, this is only true for certain Lie groups (e.g. matrix groups) and not true in general. Where am I also going wrong here?

Comment: I cannot really recall what I had written before. You can check Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups by Warner or Spin Geometry  by Lawson and Michelson. It's probably somewhere in these books.

Comment: I will check those out. In the mean time though, how does $d\pi_{gh^{-1}} \circ dR_{h^{-1}} = d\pi_g$ make sense, when the target spaces do not seem to match?