# The vector bundle $T(G/P)$ has fibre $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p}$ over each point

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, vector-bundles

In trying to answer my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526637/transferring-the-tangent-space-from-e-to-g-cdot-e-in-the-cotangent-bundle-of), I think it suffices to show that $T(G/P)$ has fibre $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p}$ over each point $gP \in G/P$, i.e. the title. Here, $P \subset G$ is any Lie subgroup, and the frakturs their corresponding Lie algebras.

My outline of ideas is that since $TG \cong G \times T_eG$, then $T(G/P) \cong G/P \times T_e(G/P) = G/P \times \mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p}$, so that $T(G/P)$ has fibre $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p}$ over each point $gP$.

However I think this is too simple, and am not sure if I am missing something else.

Comment: Is $T(G/P)$ the tangent bundle of $G/P$? If yes then $T(G/P) \cong G/P \times T_e(G/P)$ does not hold. The tangent bundle of $G/P$ is in general not a trivial bundle.

Comment: But is it not true that $TG \cong G \times T_eG$?

Comment: The tangent bundle of a Lie group is always trivial, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308691/let-g-be-a-lie-group-show-that-there-is-a-diffeomorphism-tg-cong-g-times-t). But $G/P$ has no group structure, unless $P$ is a normal subgroup. The simplest example is the Hopf fibration $SU(2)/U(1)$, which is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb S^2$

Comment: I suppose in the cases I care about, the $P$ in question is either a Borel or parabolic subgroup, so I was implicitly considering $G/P$ with quotient group structure. So in those cases this question would be correct, but in general the statement is false. This is fine, though now I wonder how Chriss-Ginzburg expect to prove their result...

Comment: What is true is that the tangent space of $G/P$ at $gP$ is canonically isomorphic to $ \mathfrak g / g \cdot \mathfrak p$.